# How should I bind to a window function in an Ember View?

Tags: ember.js

I have a mixin which automatically recalculates and sets the height of a div on  page resize.

It works but it seems silly to me to be binding to a jQuery event and triggering an Ember event manually every time it is called.

Is there a way to bind to window events directly in Ember?

I have a simplified JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kGhrx/1/)

This is the code:

```
App.windowWrapper = Ember.Object.create(Ember.Evented,
  resizeTimer: null
  init: ->
    @_super()
    object = this
    $(window).on 'resize', ->
      window.clearTimeout(object.resizeTimer)
      object.resizeTimer = setTimeout( App.windowWrapper.resize, 100)
      true

  resize: ->
    App.windowWrapper.fire('resize')
)
```

And the mixin that is calling it.

```
App.Scrollable = Ember.Mixin.create
  classNames: "scrollable"
  init: ->
    Ember.assert("Scrollable must be mixed in to a View", this instanceof Ember.View)
    @_super()

  didInsertElement: ->
    @_super()
    @calculateHeight()
    App.windowWrapper.on('resize', this, 'calculateHeight')

  willDestroyElement: ->
    App.windowWrapper.off('resize', this, 'calculateHeight')
    @_super()

  calculateHeight: ->
    offset       = @$().offset().top
    windowHeight = $(window).height()
    @$().css('height', windowHeight - offset)
```

Comment: You wouldn't need the `object = this` if you used a fat arrow (`=>`) when registering your event handler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with registering your own event handler with jQuery for something like this.

Ember doesn't have any window event handling currently.

I'd also suggest trying to come up with a solution that didn't rely on globals.

Answer (score 14):

I know I'm a few years late, but I was looking for a solution to the same problem and found this:

```
jQuery(window).on('resize', Ember.run.bind(this, this.handleResize));
```

(source: [Ember.js ofiicial](http://emberjs.com/blog/2014/02/12/ember-1-4-0-and-ember-1-5-0-beta-released.html))

**** P.S.
About the implementation of this little trick - I don't know if it's possible to use it in a controller method and trigger on init (as denis.peplin commented), I'm actually binding the event in the route's 'setupController' function. I don't know if it's best-practice, but it works like a charm in my app.

Comment: Yes, and how do you unbind it once you have it bound...?

Answer (score 3):

And sample code for `Itay Hamashmid`'s answer:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  handleResize: function() {
    console.log('resized');
  },
  bindResizeEvent: function() {
    jQuery(window).on('resize', Ember.run.bind(this, this.handleResize));
  }.on('init')
});
```

Comment: denis.peplin: The function bindResizeEvent is called on init but when I'm changing the size of the Chrome browser, the function does not run again. The expected behaviour of bindResizeEvent is that it would run each time the browser window is resized (this is what I'm looking for)?

Comment: Yes, and how do you unbind it once you have it bound...?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible with Ember.js - the only place where it provides built in DOM event handling is for Ember.View (click etc.) and maybe in other view related classes.

We also used similar approaches to your solution to handle special cases like this!

Answer (score 0):

For the ones who searching by newest answers or just get rid of jquery...

In my case I just want to know if window resized to calc width of element.

```
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  size: window.innerWidth,

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    window.addEventListener('resize', ()=> this.set('size', window.innerWidth));
  }
});
```

Yeah, I know there is no way to unbind this kind of anonymous function, but I've searched and I can't find good answers...

I thinking to refactor this to use jquery but in a restricted scope like:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import $ from 'jquery';

export default Component.extend({
  size: window.innerWidth,

  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);

    $(document.querySelector('#something'))
              .on('resize', (e)=> this.set('size', e.target.innerWidth));
  }
});
```

And this will listener will live until this component lives!