# Ember.js: bootstrapped jQuery bindings not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I'm building my first Ember app. My understanding is that [Ember doesn't have window-level bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843362/how-should-i-bind-to-a-window-function-in-an-ember-view). My layout, however, requires that some things to be resized to suit the current window.

I can bind to the window.resize() event and the callback works as anticipated. However, I also need to call the function on pageload as part of a layout initialization. It fires and returns successfully, but, nothing appears to happen (ie. the css changes don't occur, the element is unchanged)! I thought this might be because my element is in side a handlebars template, but even targeting the element thus doesn't work:

**index.html**

```
<body>
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <div id="splash-pane">
            <div class="welcome-bar"></div>
            <div class="welcome-bar"></div>
            <div id="splash-logo"></div>
    </div>
</script>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ember-1.7.0.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ember-data.js"></script>
        <script src="js/lib/bootstrap.js"></script>
        <script src="js/application.js"></script>
        <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="js/router.js"></script>
        <script src="js/views.js"></script>
</body>
```

**application.js**

```
var App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS:true,
    BOOTSTRAPPED: BS.init(),
});
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
window.BS = {
    init: function() {
        var initStatus = true;
        var sitRep = {
            scaleSplash: BS.scaleSplash(),
            jqBinds:BS.jqBinds()
        };

        for (initEl in sitRep) {
            if (!(sitRep[initEl] === true)) {
                initStatus = false;
                throw "Bootstrap failed. We're probably under attack. Hide 'ya kids."
            }
        }
        return initStatus;
    },
    jqBinds: function() {
        $(window).on("resize", BS.scaleSplash);
        return true;
    },
    scaleSplash: function() {
        var winH = window.innerHeight;
        var winW = window.innerWidth;
        // set base size to 1/3 of smallest window dimension
        var logoBase = (winH * 0.33) > (winW * 0.33) ? winW * 0.33 : winH * 0.33;
        $("#splash-logo").css({
            height:logoBase+"px",
            width:logoBase+"px",
            marginTop:String((winH - logoBase)/2)+"px"
        });

        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do your initialization after you template is rendered. You can do that using the didInsertElement event from your view. Example:

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
  didInsertElement : function(){
    this._super();
    Ember.run.scheduleOnce('afterRender', this, BS.init);
  }
});
```

more info: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#event_didInsertElement 
& about the scheduleOnce: http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/run-loop/

Comment: First time I've ever completely and actually just copied-and-pasted a solution, bravo.